# Has Parse Crash Reporting been deprecated in the 1.10.0 SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been away from Parse for just over a year and remembered they used to offer a crash reporting service on iOS, if I remember correctly in the SDK there used to be a `PareCrashReporting.framework` as part of the download bundle.

Yesterday I downloaded the 1.10.0 SDK to find there was no binary to support the ParseCrashReporting framework.   I thought this was a little weird so I decided to consult [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide) where I still found no implementation for crash reporting.

In iOS, before setting the application id and client key you used to be able to do:

```
ParseCrashReporting.enable(context)
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
Parse.setApplicationId("xyz", clientKey: "abc")
```

However without the crash reporting binary this obviously will not work.

Does anybody know how to set up Crash Reporting in 1.10 or do I need to look at an alternative provider to track my app crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an email I received from Parse.

> Hi there,
>
> At Parse, we're always working to improve your developer experience.
>   Last December, we launched Parse Crash Reporting with the goals of
>   recognizing, tracking, and ultimately resolving crashes in your app.
>
> In the time since, we've seen huge strides being made within the
>   industry's native solutions. These native experiences have the
>   advantage of being more tightly integrated into your build and release
>   process, offering a more robust, streamlined, and frictionless
>   development experience for you.
>
> The Parse Crash Reporting tool is now being deprecated in favor of
>   these great native solutions. We will continue supporting Parse Crash
>   Reporting until March 1, 2016.
>
> Here's how you can smoothly switch from Parse Crash Reporting to Apple
>   or Google's offerings:
>
> [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKXPZKXonjHpfsX86%2B8qWaSzlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASMNhI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTbHGMblmy7gNUxU%3D) |
>   [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKXPZKXonjHpfsX86%2B8qWaSzlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASMNhI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTbHGMblmy7gNUxU%3D#reviews-reports)
>
> We're constantly tackling new challenges to
>   help you build better than ever before. Please reach out if you have
>   any questions or concerns to community@parse.com.
>
> The Parse Team

Comment: Thanks a lot this was most useful, I scoured Google for hours last night and could not find anything